# Can my chrome extension open a link in a different profile?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use two different Chrome profiles (users) on my laptop: one for my work stuff and one for my personal browsing.

Sometimes I click a link from HipChat and it opens it in the personal profile even though it's for work (e.g. login.work.com).  (This is because I happen to have been in my personal chrome window most recently.)

I'd like to make a chrome extension I can install in my personal profile to match the URLs of *.work.com and send these over to the work profile window.

I haven't found a way to open a url into a different profile.  Anyone know of a way?

(A hacky idea I got from reading https://superuser.com/a/289618 is maybe I could shell out to something along the lines of `google-chrome --user-data-dir=$work_profile`, but I'd be happier if there was a JS API and I didn't have to ask permission to run programs on the user's computer.)

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a Mac application called Choosy which is perfect for this. https://www.choosyosx.com/

Comment: For what it's worth I've worked around this by using a totally different browser for my personal stuff on my work laptop (Chromium).  Now when I click a link from Slack (RIP HipChat) it always opens in my work browser since it's the default browser.  I just have to be careful to copy/paste URLs from SMS messages.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping an answer in case it's still useful to anyone.

I built my chrome extension CopyTabs (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabs/obkbjogekcjalnaebheboejhfkamadkg) to do something similar. It is able to open links, current tabs, selected tabs or windows, in the current chrome user profile, another chrome user profile or another browser entirely.

I made use of `chrome.exe --profile-directory="profileName"` to open URLs in a selected profile, but this has a handler that runs on the user's machine, with `profileName` being the internal name of the chrome profile, for example `--profile-directory="Profile1"` instead of `--profile-directory="My Name As Profile"`.

So to answer your question, no I don't think there's anyway around a local handler on the user's machine to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is an old one but maybe someone is looking for an answer.

In the new versions of chrome when you right click on a link, in the pop-up menu, there is an option to open the link in another profile. For this to work, ofcourse, there need to be multiple user profiles in Chrome.

Works like a charm!

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not the solution to the issue. The links DaveMan mentions are from external applications, so there is no right click context menu that applies.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It doesn't solve my problem but is worth knowing.

Comment: Bummer, this trick seems to have stopped working in recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works as a charm when opening Stack Overflow in the wrong profile and then not being able to upvote something. I can now right-click on the OP question header and re-open the question in my correct profile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for this. It would need a handler, a separate program, that captures the URL before it reaches Chrome, parses your preferences for which URLs go to which profile and then starts the specified Chrome installation with specified profile flags.

However, afaik, such a program does not exist (at least on Windows).

Further, Chrome cannot even select which profile out of many is selected, when Chrome is started from the OS "call URL to be opened" function and NOT started by user-activated clicking on a Chrome application shortcut (with specific profile selection instructions).

Naturally, the latter works 100% wonderfully on Firefox, which has built-in profile selector after the browser has been started, and regardless of which method was used to start Firefox (user click on Firefox icon or OS pipe of "open URL" to Firefox).

So; no solution in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Account Surfer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/account-surfer/9phvp9rjr7r7) should be able to do the things that you're looking for. Here's an overview from Windows store:

> **Quickly switch between accounts and browsers with Account Surfer.**
>
> Decide what account or browser to use when opening the link.
> Read more:
> https://dospolov.com/posts/handle-chrome-profiles-with-account-surfer
> https://trello.com/b/QOLCmlg3/account-surfer-roadmap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can:

1. install extension like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-ms-edge/mjoebkkejejidnkfdekpbooceogbapnf
2. copy address of profile (for example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2`)
3. Insert it in settings of extension
4. profit

OR

Use Browser Chooser 2

Answer (score 0):

The app finicky did the trick for me. You can check out this link for installation and configuration for the same.
[Finicky example configuration](https://github.com/johnste/finicky#example-configuration)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [edit] to add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be _helpful_, but avoid making it _necessary_ to click on them as much as possible.